# Prob. 5 (e), Sec. 4.3, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS: How to find $\lim_{x\to 0-} \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, analysis

I know that 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0+} \frac{ \sqrt{ x+1 } }{x} = +\infty. $$

Now how to find 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0- } \frac{ \sqrt{ x+1 } }{x} = +\infty? $$

This is Prob. 5 (e), Sec. 4.3, in the book *[Introduction To Real Analysis](https://sciencemathematicseducation.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/0471433314realanalysis4.pdf)* by Robert G. Bartle and Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition.

My Attempt:

> The function $f$ given by 
>   $$ f(x) \colon= \frac{ \sqrt{ x+1 } }{x} $$
>   is defined only for real numbers $x \geq -1$. Moreover, $f(x) < 0$ for $x < 0$.
>
> If $-1 < x < 0$, then 
>   $$ 0 < \sqrt{ x+1} < 1, $$
>   and so 
>   $$ \frac{1}{x} < \frac{ \sqrt{ x+1} }{x} < 0. \tag{1} $$
>
> Also if $-1 < x < 0$, then
>   $$ -\frac{1}{x} > 1, $$
>   and as $\sqrt{x+1} > 0$, so 
>   $$ - \frac{ \sqrt{ x+1} }{x} > \sqrt{x+1}, $$
>   and hence 
>   $$  \frac{ \sqrt{ x+1} }{x} < - \sqrt{x+1}. $$

What to do here?

I've really no clue of what to do. I would like to be able to majorise this function by one tending to $-\infty$ as $x \to 0-$, or I would like to bound this function between two functions that both have the same limit as $x \to 0-$.

Or, does the limit exist at all in the extended real number system $\mathbb{R} \cup \left\{ \ \pm \infty \ \right\}$?

Comment: I think you are wrong, it should be $-\infty$.

Comment: Intuitively numerator tends to 1 and numerator to 0 from the negative side therefore the LHS limit is $-\infty$. To show that rigoursly we can use for example squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{\sqrt{x + 1}}{x}
   =\frac{x + 1}{x\sqrt{x + 1}}
   =\frac{1}{\sqrt{x + 1}} + \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x + 1}}
  \to -\infty \quad  \text{as} \quad x \to 0^-
$$

Comment: @stevengregory thank you very much for such a beautiful answer! I should be cross with myself for not being able to figure it out on my own!

Answer (score 3):

We have that as $x\to 0^+$

$$\frac{ \sqrt{ x+1 } }{x}\ge \frac 1 x \to \infty$$

and as $x\to 0^-$ let $y=-x \to 0^+$ eventually as $\sqrt{ 1-y }\ge \frac12$

$$\frac{ \sqrt{ x+1 } }{x}=-\frac{ \sqrt{ 1-y } }{y}\le -\frac 1 {2y} \to -\infty$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist but the one side limits exist in $\mathbb{R} \cup \left\{ \ \pm \infty \ \right\}$.

Answer (score 3):

The stated result isn't right. $1/x \to -\infty$ as $x\to 0^-$. The numerator is bounded and positive near $x=0$, so the answer remains the same. A full proof: Since $\sqrt{1+x}$ is increasing in $x$,

$$ \frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{x} ≤ \frac{\sqrt{1+0}}{x} = \frac1x \to -\infty \quad (x\to 0^-) $$